# Calculate Earth Mover's Distance for two grayscale images

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-processing, similarities, wasserstein

I am trying to calculate EMD (a.k.a. Wasserstein Distance) for these two grayscale (299x299) images/heatmaps:

### [image: grayscale images]

Right now, I am calculating the histogram/distribution of both images. The histograms will be a vector of size 256 in which the *n*th value indicates the percent of the pixels in the image with the given darkness level. Then, using these to histograms, I am calculating the EMD using the function  `wasserstein_distance` from `scipy.stats`.

However, I am now comparing only the **intensity** of the images, but I also need to compare the **location** of the intensity of the images.

*How can I do this?*

I am thinking about obtaining a histogram for every row of the images (which results in 299 histograms per image) and then calculating the EMD 299 times and take the average of these EMD's to get a final score. Is this the right way to go?

*Other methods to calculate the similarity bewteen two grayscale are also appreciated.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having looked into it a little more than at my initial answer: it seems indeed that the original usage in computer vision, e.g. [Peleg et al. (1989)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/192468), simply matched between pixel values and totally ignored location. Later work, e.g. [Rubner et al. (2000)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1026543900054), did the same but on e.g. local texture features rather than the raw pixel values. This then leaves the question of how to incorporate location.

Doing it row-by-row as you've proposed is kind of weird: you're only allowing mass to match row-by-row, so if you e.g. slid an image up by one pixel you might have an extremely large distance (which wouldn't be the case if you slid it to the right by one pixel).

A more natural way to use EMD with locations, I think, is just to do it *directly* between the image grayscale values, including the locations, so that it measures how much pixel "light" you need to move between the two. This is then a 2-dimensional EMD, which `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` can't compute, but e.g. [the POT package](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) can with [`ot.lp.emd2`](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/all.html#ot.lp.emd2).

Doing this with POT, though, seems to require creating a matrix of the cost of moving any one pixel from image 1 to any pixel of image 2. Since your images each have $299 \cdot 299 = 89,401$ pixels, this would require making an $89,401 \times 89,401$ matrix, which will not be reasonable.

---

**Update**: probably a better way than I describe below is to use the [*sliced Wasserstein distance*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10851-014-0506-3), rather than the plain Wasserstein. This takes advantage of the fact that 1-dimensional Wassersteins are extremely efficient to compute, and defines a distance on $d$-dimesinonal distributions by taking the average of the Wasserstein distance between random one-dimensional projections of the data.

This is similar to your idea of doing row and column transports: that corresponds to two particular projections. But by doing the mean over projections, you get out a real distance, which also has [better sample complexity than the full Wasserstein](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05877).

This is implemented in [POT's `sliced` module](https://pythonot.github.io/gen_modules/ot.sliced.html), but in less-efficient code this could look like

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance

def sliced_wasserstein(X, Y, num_proj):
    dim = X.shape[1]
    ests = []
    for _ in range(num_proj):
        # sample uniformly from the unit sphere
        dir = np.random.randn(dim)
        dir /= np.linalg.norm(dir)

        # project the data
        X_proj = X @ dir
        Y_proj = Y @ dir

        # compute 1d wasserstein
        ests.append(wasserstein_distance(X_proj, Y_proj)
    return np.mean(ests)
```

(The loop here, at least up to getting `X_proj` and `Y_proj`, could be vectorized, which would probably be faster.)

---

Another option would be to simply compute the distance on images which have been resized smaller (by simply adding grayscales together). If you downscaled by a factor of 10 to make your images $30 \times 30$, you'd have a pretty reasonably sized optimization problem, and in this case the images would still look pretty different. However, this is naturally only going to compare images at a "broad" scale and ignore smaller-scale differences.

There are also, of course, computationally cheaper methods to compare the original images. You can think of the method I've listed here as treating the two images as distributions of "light" over $\{1, \dots, 299\} \times \{1, \dots, 299\}$ and then computing the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) between those distributions; one could instead compute the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) by simply
$$\operatorname{TV}(P, Q) = \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{299} \sum_{j=1}^{299} \lvert P_{ij} - Q_{ij} \rvert,$$
or similarly a [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) or other [$f$-divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence).
These are trivial to compute in this setting but treat each pixel totally separately. There are also "in-between" distances; for example, you could apply a Gaussian blur to the two images before computing similarities, which would correspond to estimating
$$
L_2(p, q) = \int (p(x) - q(x))^2 \mathrm{d}x
$$
between the two densities with a [kernel density estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). What distance is best is going to depend on your data and what you're using it for.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I have to do the following: Suppose I have two 2x2 images. Then we have:

C1=[0, 1, 1, sqrt(2)], C2=[1, 0, sqrt(2), 1], C3=[1, \sqrt(2), 0, 1], C4=[\sqrt(2), 1, 1, 0]

The cost matrix is then:

C=[C1, C2, C3, C4].

If I need to do this for the images shown above, I need to provide 299x299 cost matrices?! Sounds like a very cumbersome process. Or is there something I do not understand correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I think you have to make a cost matrix of shape `[299*299, 299*299]`. It should only be a few lines of code though, e.g. by making the matrix of indices with something like [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) and then using [`ot.utils.dist`](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/all.html#ot.utils.dist). (This will be computationally wasteful, but for input size 299 it shouldn't really matter.)

Comment: You said I need a cost matrix for each image location to each other location. Doesnt this mean I need 299*299=89401 cost matrices?

Comment: @LVDW I updated the answer; you only need one matrix, but it's really big, so it's actually not really reasonable.

Comment: One more question. Would the following also be an appropriate solution?: 1. Obtain the distribution for every 10 (or any other number) rows for both images. 2. Compare the two distributions by calculating the EMD. 3. Do the same for every 10 columns. 4. Take the average of all calculated EMD's.

Comment: I think that would be not ridiculous, but it has a slightly weird effect of making the distance very much not invariant to rotating the images 45 degrees. Whether this matters or not depends on what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: Should `np.random.rand` be `np.random.randn`? i.e. We're looking at random directions on the $N$-sphere?

Comment: @Klimaat Absolutely, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

I think for your image size requirement, maybe sliced wasserstein as @Dougal suggests is probably the best suited since 299^4 * 4 bytes would mean a memory  requirement of ~`32 GBs` for the transport matrix, which is quite huge.

For the sake of completion of answering the general question of comparing two grayscale images using EMD and if speed of estimation is a criterion, one could also consider the regularized OT distance which is available in `POT` toolbox through `ot.sinkhorn(a, b, M1, reg)` command: the regularized version is supposed to optimize to a solution faster than the `ot.emd(a, b, M1)` command.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Danica's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/404915/390475) (I don't have enough reputation for a comment), the POT library provides an implementation of the sliced Wasserstein distance, now: https://pythonot.github.io/all.html#ot.sliced_wasserstein_distance

Example:

```py
import ot

# Generate two 2D datasets
data1 = np.random.randn(299, 299)
data2 = np.random.randn(299, 299) + 0.5

# Use POT library to compute the sliced Wasserstein distance
ws_sliced_pot_1 = ot.sliced_wasserstein_distance(data1, data1)
ws_sliced_pot_2 = ot.sliced_wasserstein_distance(data1, data2)

print(f"Wasserstein Distance 1 POT:\t{ws_sliced_pot_1}")
print(f"Wasserstein Distance 2 POT:\t{ws_sliced_pot_2}")
```

Not that the library is installed via `pip install POT` or `conda install POT`, not `ot`.

Comment: For anyone interested in timings, computing `sliced_wasserstein_distance` between two random 300x300 matrices took ~3s on my machine, using 50 projections (the default). Time should be roughly linear in the number of projections.